# Cross-compiler for Linux on Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, cross-compiling

I've been reading lots of documents on the internet about creating a cross compiler for linux on mac os x but can't seam to get any to work.

It seams as if no one can help me with the question: [Getting GMP to work with GCC 4.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153231/getting-gmp-to-work-with-gcc-4-5-2)

Is there any easy'er way to create a cross compiler?

Comment: For arm and aarch64 linux targets, I maintain precompiled OSX toolchains for download: https://thinkski.github.io/osx-arm-linux-toolchains

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to build binaries for architectures different that your build host, you need far more than just a cross-compiler - you need a full-blown toolchain, which can be a real pain to create, as you probably discovered.

A couple of approaches:

- Use a proper Linux distribution in a virtual machine, such as VirtualBox. If you only want to build binaries for Linux/i386 on an MacOSX/x86_64 host, this is - in my opinion - the easiest, safest and most clean solution. It is not a cross-compiler, of course, but it works and it has the added advantage that you can actually test your executables.
- Use a script such [`crosstool-NG`](https://crosstool-ng.github.io/) (a descendant of the original [`crosstool`](http://kegel.com/crosstool/)) to automatically build the toolchain - definitely easier than building it on your own, although you may have to compromise for slightly older compiler versions.

Answer (score 7):

You need to:

1. install the xcode base build tools
2. install the optional xcode command line tools
3. install homebrew
4. install the homebrew build tools
   4.1  **brew install crosstool-ng mpfr gmp grep**
   4.2 **brew tap homebrew/dupes**
5. create a case sensitive volume using "disk utility"
6. use this volume to build the tool chain itself
   6.1  generate a base configuration (for me this is an arm cortex a8)
       6.1.1 **ct-ng arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi**
   6.2 use menuconfig (**ct-ng menuconfig**) to tweak the configuration
   6.2.1. disable fortran and java (*c compiler*)
   6.2.2. turn off static linking (*c compiler*)
   6.2.3. change the paths to be on the volume you created above (*paths and misc options*)
   6.2.4. remove dmalloc (*debug facilities*)
   6.3 invoke the build:
   6.3.1 **ulimit -n 1024**
   6.3.2 **ct-ng build**

with much thanks to the [crosstools-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) list.

Comment: That sound ... cool. But why we need a new volume to build the tool chain?

Comment: hi cxwangyi - if memory serves I did this to ensure that the volume was case sensitive. Best of luck with this. If you struggle I found the crosstools-ng list very supportive. And yes its cool :)