# cannot execute binary file error that I scpd to a different computer

Tags: g++, executable, binaryfiles

I scp'd a Unix executable file into my work computer and am receiving an error when trying to run it. If I type in:

```
./cmpDNA 4 5 0.3 > results/results4_5_0.3.txt &
```

where cmpDNA is my program, 4 5 0.3 are input parameters and results/results4_5_0.3.txt is my output file, this is the error I receive:

```
-bash: ./cmpDNA: cannot execute binary file
```

I compiled in on my OS X computer using g++ and made sure to include my -m32 for a 32 bit build as the target computer is 32-bit Ubuntu. Typing:

```
file cmpDNA
```

gets:

```
cmpDNA: Mach-O executable i386
```

So I'm not sure why it won't execute. I've been looking for awhile but I can't find any answers that solve my problem. All users have executable permissions as well. Here were all of my compile options if that helps:

```
g++ -Wall -std=gnu++0x -o cmpDNA -m32 files.cpp
```

Thanks!

Comment: A program compiled with a Mac OS X compiler won't run on Ubuntu. Why do you expect any other result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not compile on OS X without using a cross compiler and run on Ubuntu. Here is the answer that I found:
[Compiling C Program on OS X to Run on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990333/compiling-c-program-on-os-x-to-run-on-ubuntu)