# Can I build mex for linux on mac?

Tags: matlab, cross-compiling, mex

Is it possible to use MATLAB on macOS to build a mex file for running on linux (with the `.mexa64` extension)? Suppose that I have an appropriate compiler such as GCC. How would I do this? I couldn't find any useful arguments in [`mex`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html).

I understand building for a different platform would [require a full toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245444/cross-compiler-for-linux-on-mac-os-x), but I'm wondering if MATLAB has one already under the hood.

Comment: MATLAB has nothing under the hood. To compile something you need a different compiler, so that different compiler is the one that must be able to do the job, AFAIK.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but [this](https://github.com/rejuvyesh/homepage/blob/master/posts/2013-12-13-cross-compile-matlab-mex-files-on-linux.md) might be helpful.